# Как добавить статичный ресурс как элемент коллекции

Tags: wpf, xaml

Можно значением свойства выставить статический ресурс таким образом

```
<Anything SomeAttribute="{StaticResource someResource}"/>
```

само собой `someResource` должен быть определен в ресурсах. А что, если нужное свойство имеет тип коллекции и мне нужно добавить в него элемент?

```
<Anything>
    <Anything.SomeCollection>
         ВОТ СЮДА НАДО ДОБАВИТЬ ВСЕГО ОДИН ЭЛЕМЕНТ someResource 
    <Anything.SomeCollection>
</Anything>
```